# Dynamically added rows to TableLayout not showing up

Tags: android-layout, android, android-tablelayout

I'm trying to add rows to TableLayout at runtime but the data is simply not showing up.

XML:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="1" >

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbarSize="10dp"
        android:scrollbars="horizontal|vertical" >

        <TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/server_dataTable"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            android:background="@color/color_data_table_header_background"
            android:stretchColumns="*" >
        </TableLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

The relevant code:

```
private TableLayout addRowToTable(TableLayout table, String[] data) {
    Context context = this.getApplicationContext();
    TableRow row = new TableRow(context);

    TableLayout.LayoutParams rowParams = new TableLayout.LayoutParams();
    // Wrap-up the content of the row
    rowParams.height = TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
    rowParams.width = TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;

    for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        TableRow.LayoutParams columnParams = new TableRow.LayoutParams();
        // wrap-up content of the row
        columnParams.height = TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
        columnParams.width = TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
        // set gravity to center of the column
        columnParams.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
        TextView column = new TextView(context);
        column.setText(data[i]);
        row.addView(column, columnParams);
    }

    table.addView(row, rowParams);

    return table;
}
```

I'm calling `addRowToTable` from my activity's onCreate():

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_server);
    // Show the Up button in the action bar.
    setupActionBar();

    TableLayout dataTableHeader = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.server_dataTable);
    dataTableHeader = addRowToTable(dataTableHeader, headerLabels);
}
```

I've been at this for about 40 minutes now and have already read almost all related questions on StackOverflow but haven't found anything helpful. Any help/pointers would be great!

Edit: Added the activity's onCreate().

Comment: Is your `addRowToTable` running on the UI thread?

Comment: Yeah! Should I thread it?

Comment: addRowToTable() where your calling this method

Comment: @srikanth from the activity's onCreate. Check my edit.

Comment: Your context should not be getApplicationContext, it should be the Activity

Comment: Pass Activity context and try **TableRow row = new TableRow(youractivity.this);** and also at the last   **table.addView(row);**

Comment: @SimplePlan, getActivity() and getApplicationContext().getCurrentActivity() aren't working. How do I get the activity context?

Comment: @AbhishekBhardwaj then passed into your method like `addRowToTable(Activity  a,TableLayout table, String[] data)` and used like `TableRow row = new TableRow(a.this);`

Comment: How do I get that `Activity a`?

Comment: Also, `a.this` gives a ` cannot be resolved to a type` error. Just `a` works..but I don't know how to get the activity context.

Answer (score 1):

Passed `Activity` context into your  `addRowToTable` method like

```
dataTableHeader = addRowToTable(youractivity.this,dataTableHeader, headerLabels);
```

and Access into `addRowToTable` like:

```
private TableLayout addRowToTable(Activity a,TableLayout table, String[] data) {
TableRow row = new TableRow(a);
........
........
table.addView(row);

return table;
}
```

Try this way and give me feedback

**Update:** try out this way:

```
private TableLayout addRowToTable(Activity a,TableLayout table, String[] data) {
TableRow row = new TableRow(a);

row.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

    TableRow.LayoutParams columnParams = new TableRow.LayoutParams();
    // wrap-up content of the row
    columnParams.height = TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
    columnParams.width = TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
    // set gravity to center of the column
    columnParams.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
    TextView column = new TextView(a);
    column.setText(data[i]);
    row.addView(column,columnParams);
}

table.addView(row);

return table;
}
```

Comment: @AbhishekBhardwaj now,tell me one thing **headerLabels** check this is not null and/or where you add data on **headerLabels**?

Comment: Not null. I tried outputting `column.getText().toString()` to LogCat right after `column.setText()` and it outputted the label names.

Comment: @AbhishekBhardwaj i m done with this i successfully show four header labels

Comment: @AbhishekBhardwaj show me your all code where u bind  headerLabels